# Could not find path to c:\

Tags: vb.net

I created an app(exe) with visual studio 2012 it runs fine in vs but after installing on a different
computer I get an error

> could not find path c:\Program Files\our family\database1.sbf"

Here is some code:

```
    If (FolderBrowserDialog1.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK) Then
        ChDir(Path:=FolderBrowserDialog1.SelectedPath)
        FileCopy("C:\Program Files(86)\Our Family\Database1.sdf", "DataBase1.sdf ")
        FileCopy("C:\Program Files(x86)\Our Family\Database1.sdf", "DataBase1 .log")
        Try
            MessageBox.Show("YOUR DATA FILES HAVE BEEN BACKEDUP Succesfully", "Information")
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End If
```

I can't figure it out any help would be great. Thanks Gene

Comment: Either the file doesn't exist on the computer on which you installed the app or the directory you are looking for doesn't exist.

Comment: So, you immediately went and looked for the file `c:\Program Files\our family\database1.sbf` on the second computer and found... What?

Comment: On my machine there is a space ` ` inbetween `Files` and `(86)`

Comment: Firstly, please post code properly. If you couldn't be bothered cleaning up the garbage characters in your code to make it easier for us to read, why should we be bothered to help you with your problems.

Comment: Secondly, stop writing VB.NET code like it was VB6. If you want to perform file operations then use the `System.IO.File` class. Tp copy a file, `File.Copy` is what you want.

Comment: Finally, don't hard-code paths like that. Use the `Environment.GetFolderPath` method or the `My.Computer.FileSystem.SpecialDirectories` property to get standard paths, including this one. You can then use the `Path.Combine` method to combine partial paths.

Comment: Why do you think you need an exception handler to show a message box?